# BottomNavigationView has no animation when clicking on its items

Tags: android

I have set up a `BottomNavigationView` as follows:

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottomNavigation"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:itemIconTint="@drawable/nav_item_color_state"
    app:itemTextColor="@drawable/nav_item_color_state"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation"></android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView>
```

Functions getting called on `BottomNavigationView`:

```
bottomNavigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(object: BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
        override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {

            return true
        }
    })
```

`nav_item_color_state.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item android:color="@android:color/white" android:state_enabled="true"/>
<item android:color="@color/colorPrimaryDark" android:state_enabled="false"/>
```

I have confirmed that animations are enabled both on the simulator and my device. The tutorials I have seen are getting animations. What am I doing wrong? After I click on one of the items on the `BottomNavigationItem`, it suddenly shifts with no animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/menu_timeline_selected" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/menu_timeline_selected" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/menu_timeline_selected" android:state_selected="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/menu_timeline_default" />
</selector>
```

Comment: I don't have `menu_timeline_selected` and `menu_timeline_default`

Comment: it is just drawable

<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />